# How to use Entity Framework with Union and Top N Percent?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, union, webmethod

I am using code below to get data. Code works fine but it is making too many calls to db. Is there a better and faster way to get data? I have to use TOP N PERCENT and UNION the results. Thanks.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static IEnumerable<Product> GetData()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
             var query1 = "SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM Products where CategoryID=1";
             var query2 = "SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM Products where CategoryID=2";
             var query3 = "SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM Products where CategoryID=3";
             var query4 = "SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM Products where CategoryID=4";
             var query5 = "SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM Products where CategoryID=5";

             IEnumerable<Product> p1 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query1);
             IEnumerable<Product> p2 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query2);
             IEnumerable<Product> p3 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query3);
             IEnumerable<Product> p4 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query4);
             IEnumerable<Product> p5 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query5);

             IEnumerable<Feed> all = p1.Union(p2).Union(p3).Union(p4).Union(p5);

            return all.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I have to use TOP N PERCENT for all the queries and ef does'nt have a function for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use parameters instead of concatenation, but something like this should work:

```
var ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var percentages = new[] { 10, 9, 8, 10, 9 };
var query = string.Join(" UNION ",
   ids.Zip(percentages, (id, percentage) => new { id, percentage })
    .Select(x => "SELECT TOP " + x.percentage +
                " PERCENT * FROM Products where CategoryID=" + x.id));
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query);
return results.ToList();
```

(when you're just concatenating numbers, there's not much risk, but if you try to concatenate almost any sort of `string` input, you should use parameters to prevent SQL injection)

Comment: Thanks.This looks great. How can i use one more array for different percentages? I am using percentage as a parameter too.

Comment: @user3058182 I've added an example that `Zip`s together the ids and percentages into an anonymous type that pairs them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynmicLibrary(http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and then you can use the advantage of Take and Skip.

For example:

```
var query1 = Products.Take(10).Where(c=>c.CategoryID=1);
var query2 = Products.Take(10).Where(c=>c.CategoryID=2);
```

At the end after joining you can call `.ToList();`

You can also combine them in one `IQueryable` query and you can apply another Linq operations on joined result.

Comment: But this way still sending request to db for every query and i need to take 10 percent of product not just 10 product. If i try to use ef i have to calculate the percentage and that will make another call to db for every query.

Comment: Then why you do not just use StoredProcedure? in EF5 you can very easy call a stored procedure better then a plan SQL query this will have sometimes an impact on your SW architecture.

Comment: Create a stroed procedure from Tim soultion and provide the sql parameters by calling.

Comment: I have been using stored procedures for long time i am new to EF and trying to see what i can do with it. I feel like Tsql and stored procedures are still more powerfull.